# how to hit link through array values

Tags: php

In $iptv it has two ids e.g(1,2) coming from database and these ids fetching url form 'server url' table. so when run the code it hit only first id url with the data but not hiting the second id url.

``````````````````````````````````
         `````````````````````````````````         
         }elseif ($select_type == 'iptv') {
                        $sql=$sql="SELECT * FROM `main_partner` WHERE `id`='$partner_id'";
                          $result= myQuery($sql);
                          while($row= myFetchArray($result)){
                            $iptv=$row['cspiptv'];
                            $iptv54=explode(",",$iptv);

                         foreach ($iptv54 as $value){
                          
                              if($value != 0){
                                 $sql1="SELECT * FROM `server_url` WHERE `given_id`='$iptv'";
                                 $result1= myQuery($sql1);

                                  while($row1= myFetchArray($result1)){
                                 
                                      $url=$row1['url'];
                                  
                                     $url1=$url."data.php?login=".$login."&password=".$password."&expire=".$expire_date."&user_mode=".$user_mode."&mac_id=".$mac."&iptv=".$enable."&bouquet_ids=".$bonguet_id;  
                                  
                                           header('location:'.$url1); 
                                      
                                  }
                                 
                                }
                                 
                              }
                              
                         } 
                          

                       }
``````````````````````````````````

Comment: You can't perform two redirections inside the same script. What are you tring to achieve here, exactly?

Comment: I want to store data to another database through GET method while hitting the link with data

Comment: You should look into using `cURL`.

Comment: This is not a coding service.  Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.  You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.  Telling the person commenting to write the code for you is in appropriate.  It's your job to investigate cURL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                     elseif ($select_type == 'iptv') {
                        $sql="SELECT * FROM `main_partner` WHERE `id`='$partner_id'";
                          $result= myQuery($sql);
                          while($row= myFetchArray($result)){
                            $iptv=$row['cspiptv'];
                            $iptv54=explode(",",$iptv);
                           
                            $array = array();

                         foreach ($iptv54 as $value){
                          
                              if($value != 0){
                                 $sql1="SELECT * FROM `server_url` WHERE `given_id`='$value'";
                                 $result1= myQuery($sql1);
                      
                                   while($row1= myFetchArray($result1)){
                                 
                                     $url=$row1['url'];
                                     $url1=$url."data.php?login=".$login."&password=".$password."&expire=".$expire_date."&user_mode=".$user_mode."&mac_id=".$mac."&iptv=".$enable."&bouquet_ids=".$bonguet_id;  
                                    
                                    array_push($array,$url1);
                                    
                                   }
                                }  
                              }
                              
                              $result = getResult($array);
                         } 
                          

                       }
```

```
function callCURL($url) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $combined = curl_exec ($ch);
  curl_close ($ch);
  return $combined;
}

function getResult($urls) {
 
  $return = array();

  foreach ($urls as $url) {
  
      $response = callCURL($url);
      if (strlen($response) !== 0) {
          $return[] = $response;
          break;
      }
  }
  return $return;
}
```